# A virtual ftp-server for Windows like ProFTPD

Tags: windows, mysql, postgresql, ftp

Is there any solution for Windows which allows creating virtual ftp-server with the user's storage in a MySQL or a PostgreSQL database? Something like ProFTPD for Unix.
Thanks for any advice and suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like http://wiki.iaso.com/index.php/Manual:Management_Engine_installation_with_FTP_with_MySQL_authentication_and_home_folder_autocreation for this matter.

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks like this is the application which I need. But, unfortunately, it isn't free software. I'll try to search something like this but free. If I don't find it, I'll have to use the application you are suggesting.